# Show tangent cone and linearized fesible directions of this set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

> Consider a feasible set $\Omega = \{(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2: -x_2 \leq 0\ and \ x_2-{x_1}^2\leq 0 \} $. For $x^*={(0,0)}^T$. Determine if the tangent cone and linearized feasible solutions are equal.

I am having difficulty in finding the tangent cones. I built sequences $(w_1/k,w_2/k)$, where $w_1 \neq0 \ and \ w_2 \geq0$ and $(w_1/k,{w_1}^2/k^2)$, where $w_1 \in \mathbb{R}$. By definition of tangent cone, I have to find all vectors tangent to $\Omega$ at $x^*$. So I am not sure if I have covered all vectors.

Comment: Hang on, your point is $0$. Aren't you looking at all tangent vectors such that $(t,x) < 0$ (so that the $t$ \in \Omega)? But your point is at $0$...

Comment: notice that the linearized feasible solutions is a super set of the tangent cone. The only possible candidates for the tangent directions are $(d_1, 0)$, $d_1\in\mathbb R$, ...

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question while looking for something else, and I'm not familiar with the syntax on this site.
You can rewrite the functions to:
$x_2\ge0$ and $x_2\le x_1^2$. Since $(0,0)$ is your only feasible point, your tangent cone is the point $(0,0)$. For the linearized feasible directions there is only the $x$-axis. Therefore the tangent cone and the linearized tangent cone are not the same.